# XQuery: differences between two query

Tags: database, xquery

These two queries, apparently equal, give different output. Why? What is happening exactly?

**Query 1:**

```
for $n in doc("restaurants.xml")/restaurants/restaurant
where $n/name = "PizzaKebab"
return <Dish>{$n/dish/name}</Dish>
```

**Output 1:**

```
<Dish>
  <name>Pizza</name>
  <name>Kebab</name>
</Dish>
```

**Query 2:**

```
for $n in doc("restaurants.xml")/restaurants/restaurant[name="PizzaKebab"]
return <Dish>{$n/dish/name}</Dish>
```

**Output 2:**

```
<Dish>
  <name>Pizza</name>
</Dish>
<Dish>
  <name>Kebab</name>
</Dish>
```

**restaurants.xml**

```
<restaurants>
  <restaurant>
    <name>PizzaKebab</name>
    <dish>
      <name>Pizza</name>
      <price>6</price>
    </dish>
    <dish>
      <name>Kebab</name>
      <price>3</price>
    </dish>
  </restaurant>
</restaurants>
```

Comment: Please post restaurants.xml to provide a complete context.

Comment: @joewiz Sure! I added a simple example

Comment: Well, if your input xml is truly the same for both query the answer is simple: Your processor has a bug. The second output is simply incorrect. So the question is: What XQuery processor are you using? You might want to let the developers know. However, given that your query is very basic it seems strange that would be a bug in a well-established processor...?!

Comment: Thank you for you answers because I got confusing too due to simplicity of the two queries. I am using the Java software BaseX version 8.6.7, just to train the query language!Should I use another software?

Comment: @BigMeister No, BaseX is an excellent XQuery processor (but I am certainly biased...) and I am sure that such a trivial bug is not possible in a released BaseX version (without a major outcry from users). There is certainly something else going on (e.g. you having opened another xml document).

Answer (score 2):

Your queries are functionally identical. To prove this, your processor should return `true()` for the following query - which it does in all of my tests with eXist 3.6.1, BaseX 8.6.7, and Saxon 9.7.0.19.

```
xquery version "3.1";

let $restaurants := 
    document {
        <restaurants>
            <restaurant>
                <name>PizzaKebab</name>
                <dish>
                    <name>Pizza</name>
                    <price>6</price>
                </dish>
                <dish>
                    <name>Kebab</name>
                    <price>3</price>
                </dish>
            </restaurant>
        </restaurants>
    }
let $query1 := 
    for $n in $restaurants/restaurants/restaurant
    where $n/name = "PizzaKebab"
    return <Dish>{$n/dish/name}</Dish>
let $query2 := 
    for $n in $restaurants/restaurants/restaurant[name="PizzaKebab"]
    return <Dish>{$n/dish/name}</Dish>
return
    deep-equal($query1, $query2)
```

Comment: Actually, restarting the software, it shows only the first output, maybe it entered in a kind of strange bug. Just to clarify, I was sure that the second output was right. Why the return does not display twice the <Dish>..</Dish> tag?

Comment: If you remove the `deep-equal` function from my query and return just the sequence `($query1, $query2)`, you will see that both of your FLWOR expressions return `<Dish><name>Pizza</name<name>Kebab</name></Dish>`. That is the expected result of both FLWOR expressions, given the `restaurants.xml` you provided. If my original query returns `true` for you, but you're still seeing different results in your scenario, then there must be some additional factor at play there beyond what we are seeing. How are you storing `restaurants.xml` into your database? What does `doc("restaurants.xml")` return?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear enough. Now I see the right results but before knowing the exact answer I was thinking that the second one was right. Why the return does not return twice the <Dish>...</Dish> tag has displayed in the second output?

Comment: Because that is not what your query is expressing. Basically it says: Please give me every `<name/>` element for each restaurant and put them into an enclosing `<dish/>` element. If you would have multiple `<restaurant/>` elements (with at least one such `<name/>`) you will also have multiple resulting `<dish/>` elements.

Comment: Your FLWOR expression only produces one `<Dish>` element because the for clause iterates over `<restaurant>` elements, and there is only one of those. So: for every restaurant element you return a single Dish element, which contains the child dish names.